# What are the differences between the 4 ways to define a function?

Tags: julia

In terms of scoping, implementation, performance, and usage.

1. ```
   function test1(x)
    return x + 1
   end
   ```
2. ```
   test2(x) = x + 1
   ```
3. ```
   test3 = function (x)
    return x + 1
   end
   ```
4. ```
   test4 = x -> x + 1
   ```

Comment: nothing/personal preference? you may see the native "compiled" code with `@code_native test1(1)` etc

Comment: 1. and 2. are identical. They are both ordinary function declarations with different styles. 3. and 4. are also identical, they both create anonymous functions and assign them to a variable.

Comment: There is also binary function declaration syntax: using `struct Foo; x; end` for example: `import Base: +; x::Foo + y::Foo = x.x + y.x` returns `+ (generic function with 164 methods)` which is just the same as the others, de. `+(x::Foo, y:Foo) = x.x + y.x`